# Insert Table Row and Remove button from original row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I've got a form with a table with originally 1 row of input fields. Users can click the "New Row" button to get another row, with empty input fields. This leaves with me multiple copies of the "New Row" button for every Row - I would like to remove all but the most recently created "New Row" button (i.e. the one in the last row of input fields).

I've setup a sample JSFiddle at:

http://jsfiddle.net/fmdataweb/vRe9v/2/

Is there something I can add to the existing js that will delete the button that was clicked whilst leaving the newly created button in the new row? Here's the Javascript:

```
var table = $( '#nextYear' )[0];

$( table ).delegate( '#button2', 'click', function () {
    var thisRow = $( this ).closest( 'tr' )[0];
   $( thisRow ).clone().insertAfter( thisRow ).find( 'input:text' ).val( '' );
});
```

​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$(this).remove();` jQuery $(this) in the event of control represents the control whom event is fired on. You can use `remove()` method that will remove the button being click from `dom`

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/vRe9v/5/)**

```
var table = $('#nextYear')[0];

$(table).delegate('#button2', 'click', function() {

    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(thisRow).clone().insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');
    $(this).remove();
});​
```

Comment: You wouldn't have any idea how to add some code to this to also increment the ID's for all the fields in the new row at the same time by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) which removes the set of matched elements from the DOM.

In your case as you are within the button click event, `this` is what references the button object in the DOM.

Turn `this` into a jQuery object and call [**remove()**](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on it like this:

```
$(this).remove();
```

Complete new code:

```
var table = $('#nextYear')[0];

$(table).delegate('#button2', 'click', function() {
    var thisRow = $(this).closest('tr')[0];
    $(thisRow).clone().insertAfter(thisRow).find('input:text').val('');

    $(this).remove(); // remove button that was clicked
});​
```

See [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/vRe9v/3/)

Comment: Thanks François that works great, and thanks for your explanation that helps me understand the process.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/xRQs8/2/

It can be done using single button :+

```
<table id="dataTable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>
                                                <input type="Button" value="Add More" name="AddMore" class="AddOption" />
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
```